# How to get an email address and other info like name and phone together after getting access token LinkedIn signup API with PHP

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am able to gent email using `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))` and able to get name and profile pic using `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me`.My question is that how can i get it together.Is there any single API to call and get all profile info together?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api) says something about lite and basic profile permissions but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to get both in one query.

Profile Json Response:

```
{
   "firstName":{
      "localized":{
         "en_US":"Bob"
      },
      "preferredLocale":{
         "country":"US",
         "language":"en"
      }
   },
   "localizedFirstName": "Bob",
   "headline":{
      "localized":{
         "en_US":"API Enthusiast at LinkedIn"
      },
      "preferredLocale":{
         "country":"US",
         "language":"en"
      }
   },
   "localizedHeadline": "API Enthusiast at LinkedIn",
   "vanityName": "bsmith",
   "id":"yrZCpj2Z12",
   "lastName":{
      "localized":{
         "en_US":"Smith"
      },
      "preferredLocale":{
         "country":"US",
         "language":"en"
      }
   },
   "localizedLastName": "Smith",
   "profilePicture": {
        "displayImage": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4D00AAAAbBCDEFGhiJ"
   }
}
```

Contact Json Response:

```
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "handle": "urn:li:emailAddress:3775708763",
            "handle~": {
                "emailAddress": "ding_wei_stub@example.com"
            },
            "primary": true,
            "type": "EMAIL"
        },
        {
            "handle": "urn:li:phoneNumber:6146249836070047744",
            "handle~": {
                "phoneNumber": {
                    "number": "158****1473"
                }
            },
            "primary": true,
            "type": "PHONE"
        }
    ]
}
```

The reason might be that there are separated APIs, Contact API and Profile API.